# Swift 4 Referencing a UITextField programatically

Tags: swift

Relatively new to coding in Swift and am well on my way to my first App, however, this issue is totally foxing me and I cannot work out why.

Why can I not reference the InputTextField.text property?

[Playground image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qim2W.png)

```
//: A UIKit based Playground for presenting user interface

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {

    override func loadView() {
        setupInputView()
    }


    func setupInputView () {
        let InputTextField = UITextField()
        InputTextField.text = "Some Text"


        view.addSubview(InputTextField)

    }

}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()

print("InputTextField: \(InputTextField.text)")
```

Comment: the print is giving error because the InputTextField was declared inside a function.

Comment: also, you must change the name from InputTextField to inputTextField

Comment: You should not be overriding `loadView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InputTextField has been declared inside the function setupInputView(). It is only accessible inside that function. Move the declaration

```
let InputTextField = UITextField()
```

outside the function. It will then be a member of your class MyViewController. Outside of that class you can access as follows

```
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView.InputTextField
```

Go read up on scope and variable declarations before you continue

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is, you are setting up the textField inside a function. So the textField variable has a local scope and it's become inaccessible with myViewController instance. So first of all, you have to make the textField as a global variable. Please see the code snippet below-

```
class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    let inputTextField = UITextField()

    override func loadView() {
        inputTextField.text = "some text"
    }
}
let myViewController = MyViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = myViewController
print("TextFieldValue: \(myViewController.inputTextField.text!)")
```

Please remember one thing about the variable naming convention, it's always start with small letter and then follow camelCasing.

Comment: Do not override `loadView` like this.